# Proof for the probability that $A[i]<A[j]$ in a random permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I'm studying a proof on the expected number of inversions in a permutation of $n$ numbers. The numbers are distinct integers from $1$ to $n$. At some points it takes as given that chosen two indices $(i,j)$ the probability that $A[i]<A[j]$ is $1/2$. Could somebody please give me a formal proof for this?

**Edit:**
I think I came up with a proof for that.
We choose two elements from the permutation. There are ${n\choose 2}$ ways to place them in 2 of $n$ different positions using the position with the smallest index to store the smallest of the 2 elements (This denotes the fact that $A[i]<A[j]$). Then there are $(n-2)!$ permutations to store the remaining $n-2$ elements. Our sample space is $n!$ so:
$P(A[i]<A[j])=\frac{{n\choose 2}(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{n!}{2n!}=\frac{1}{2}$

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if my logic is correct.

Comment: Do you mean a permutation chosen at random trom the full symmetric group? Then note that all the numbers 1 to n are equivalent: they are all just arbitrary labels for the elements of the set you are permuting. So if you 'relabel' 1 as n, 2 as n-1, etc, this should not change the probability. Since this relabelling exactly swaps whether or not A[i]<A[j], the probability must have been half to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but there are simpler ways to see this. Interchanging the entries $A[i]$ and $A[j]$ defines a map $f$ from permutations to permutations which composed with itself ($f\circ f$) gives the identity on the set of all permutations (it is an involution of that set). So in particular $f$ is a bijection; it also maps the subset of permutations with $A[i]<A[j]$ percisely to those with $A[i]>A[j]$, so the two subsets have equal size, and each contain half of all permutations.

A similar argument where one replaces each entry $i$ by the complementary entry $n+1-i$ also works. (Reversing the order of the whole permutation however does not work, as is will map the positions $i,j$ to a different pair of positions).